# R: What happens if randomForest() generates boostrapped constants?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, imputation

The algorithm implemented in `randomForest()` generates bootstrapped data. It is possible that it generates variables with zero variation. In this case, are these bootstrapped constants dropped before `mtry` candidate variables are selected or are they drawn then dropped from the pool of candidate variables?

Relatedly, we can imagine a case where all of the bootstrapped variables exhibit zero variation. What does the package do in such edge cases?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the original paper from Breiman (2001), nothing excludes the possibility that bootstrap may generate variables with near-zero variance. BUT..., this is not a big issue in the contest of random forests algorithm, which is based on the growth of numerous decision trees that are weakly correlated with each other.

In random forests, the bagging (bootstrap aggregation) procedure is used to reduce the variance for those algorithms that have high variance, like decision trees (CART for instance). Decision trees are sensitive to the specific data on which they are trained. If the training data is changed (e.g. a tree is trained on a subset of the training data) the resulting decision tree can be quite different and in turn, the predictions can be quite different.

But, when bagging with decision trees, we are less concerned about individual trees overfitting the training data. This is why the individual decision trees are grown deep (e.g. few training samples at each leaf-node of the tree) and the trees are not pruned. These trees will have both high variance and low bias. These are important characteristics of sub-models when combining predictions using bagging.

There is at least one problem when dealing with bagged decision trees like CART: they are greedy. They choose which variable to split on using a greedy algorithm that minimizes error. As such, even with Bagging, the decision trees can have a lot of structural similarities and in turn, have a high correlation in their predictions.

Is here that Breiman finds a solution, by injecting even more randomness into the construction of the trees.  In CART, when selecting a split point, the learning algorithm is allowed to look through all variables and all variable values in order to select the most optimal split-point. The random forest algorithm changes this procedure so that the learning algorithm is limited to a random sample of features of which to search (this number is selected by the `mtry` parameter).

All this to say that, even if a variable with zero-variance is produced, the algorithm is built specifically to be resistant to the weaknesses of individual decision trees. All this to say that, even if a zero-variance variable is produced, the algorithm is purpose-built to be resistant to the weaknesses of individual decision trees. In the voting process, the erroneous prediction of the single tree is dampened by the rest of the forest.

This not respond to your question "how the algorithm deal with the near-zero variance predictors" but it serves to say that it is actually not a real problem in random forests

Comment: Yes, the question was simply if mtry is the # of variables sampled, then variables with 0 variance as dropped such that the actual number of variables is <= mtry or whether those variables are dropped beforehand.